# Переводчик языков программирования

Tags: транслятор

Интересно, существуют ли хотя бы какие-нибудь заготовки переводчиков для языков программирования. Вопрос может показаться немного странным, но все же интересно узнать.
Например, прикольно бы было перевести код с Pascal'я на C++, с C++ на человеческий =)
Хотя и разработать что-то подобное будет непросто....

---

Что-то самому даже стало как-то чересчур интересно, может попробовать что-нибудь подобное накатать на коленке?

Comment: Человеческих языков, не считая диалектов и мертвых, около 300. Мобыть в блок-схемы как-то можно перевести. Вообще это какая-то декомпиляция алгоритма в поток сознания))

Comment: хех =) ну да... Ну не обязательно встраивать все человеческие языки. Для начала вполне хватит перевода Pascal->C++ | C++->Pascal. Про нечисть, типа BrainFuck и Unlambda можно молчать...

Comment: Кстати, это называется "транслятор". Мостики между языками с переменным успехом разрабатываются, можно нагуглить. А вот про "без работы" не согласен. Перевод С->PHP вообще бессмысленный, например. ASM->русский тоже))

Comment: Ну, как известно, ядро PHP написано на C++. А вот про асм согласен, там на русском не объяснишь что значат мувы и еаксы...

Comment: единственное, что у меня из трансляторов заработало это BF->C

Comment: И как? Все грамотно транслировалось? Или полно багов? =)

Comment: @Sh4dow, в настоящее время живых языков в мире около 5-6 тысяч. )))

Comment: Не могли бы вы их перечислить, пожалуйста =) :D

Comment: >А вот про асм согласен, там на русском не объяснишь что значат мувы и еаксы...

А я не согласен) Объяснить-то можно, но смысла в этом нет)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@nikita_sergeevich](/users/5925/nikita_sergeevich) правильно сказал, но всё-же между **схожими** языками перевод возможен:

[Cpp в Delphi](http://jvc2d.sourceforge.net/)

[Много разных "переводчиков"](http://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/)

[JLCA](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=14349)

Comment: Да, тем более C++ и Delphi оба объектные языки. Можно для начала хотя бы переводить элементы ООП одного языка в другой =)
"Много разных переводчиков" - действительно много, интересно узнать из истинный функционал...

---------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: Нету такого языка **Delphi**
Почему?! Почему люди так старательно называют **Object Pascal** как _Delphi_  
Это всего лишь ИНТЕРФЕЙС...  
P.S. уже хочется плакать

Comment: Опять "ж..па есть, а слова нет"? Стандарт на Object Pascal есть? Пусть есть, я не знаю. Далее --  диалект в Delphi соответствует ему на 100%? Вряд ли. Значит диалект надо как-то называть. Человек называет по имени "интерфейса". Зато всем понятно.

Comment: Из википедии: Delphi — императивный, структурированный, объектно-ориентированный язык программирования, диалект Object Pascal. Начиная со среды разработки Delphi 7.0, в официальных документах Borland стала использовать название Delphi для обозначения языка Object Pascal. Начиная с 2007 года уже язык Delphi (производный от Object Pascal) начал жить своей самостоятельной жизнью и претерпевал различные изменения,... и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Яркий пример - декомпилятор, который переводит с одного языка (машинный) на другой. Декомпилирует-то он, да, но как - это другой вопрос. Везде одни ошибки. Тоже самое с переводом одних человеческий языков на другой - машинный перевод не точен. Пока не существует таких мощностей чтобы можно было реализовать подобную идею.

Answer (score 0):

Есть. Как-то баловался `f2c` - переводчик с Фортрана77 на Си. Гадость неимоверная.

Comment: Да ладно гадость... очень даже выручал меня в свое время f2c

Comment: Гадость. Мне было проще самому переписать на Си, чем разбираться с тем, что он выдал.

Answer (score -1):

Синтаксис 1С отдаленно напоминает человеческий, чем-то похож на текст телеграммы — без склонений, предлогов, сокращенный. Вы это имели в виду?

Comment: Если Оклад > 10000 Тогда
......Результат = "Нормально";

ИначеЕсли Оклад > 5000 Тогда
......Результат = "Средне";

Иначе
......Результат = "Плохо";
КонецЕсли;

Comment: Ну не очень-то похож. Но такой язык есть (был?). Кобол. Цель -- чтобы бухгалтер, не наш, англоязычный, мог программу прочитать и понять (если сумеет). Пример оператора:

   ADD GIN TO VERMOUTH GIVING MARTINI.

Comment: Хех) Я скажу только, что ни капли не знаком с 1C и всеми их программными продуктами, но русский синтаксис порадовал ! Прикольно писать софт(или запросы) на русском, правда чувствуешь себя, мягко говоря, простачком. =)

Comment: 1C это не язык программирования, а язык конфигурации (ИМХО) сделать его читабельным не так сложно по причине того, что он решает конкретную узкую сферу задач.

Comment: Ага, а Borland Delphi — графический редактор.

Comment: И это тоже xDDD

Answer (score -5):

Переводчиков нету. Особенно таких какие вы хотите :) Pascal это обычное структурированное(структурное) программирование, а C++ это объектно-ориентированный язык.
В разных языках свои нюансы, перевод будет затруднителен. Да и зачем такое нужно. Без работы оставите людей такими программами))

Comment: вы сильно ошибаетесь! есть такие трансляторы! А в Object Pascal есть объектно-ориентированное программирование.
И даже круче - Object Pascal можно транслировать не только на С++, но и на java (уж он то 100% изначально  Объектно-ориентированный), на javaScript, на фортран и на кучу других языков.